# How do I show one page to logged-in user and another to a not-logged in user with Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm confident that this question has been asked before, but I can't find an answer here.

**The goal**: show a user that isn't logged in a random assortment of posts but a user that *is* logged in all of their own posts.

The two views from views.py:

```
def movement_random(request):
    movements = Movement.objects.order_by('?')[:10]
    return render(request, 'blog/movement_random.html', {'movements': movements})

@login_required
def movement_list(request):
    movements = Movement.objects.filter(author=request.user).order_by('-moved_on')
    return render(request, 'blog/movement_list.html', {'movements': movements})
```

From urls.py:

from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.movement_random, name='index'),
    url(r'^$', views.movement_list, name='movement_list'), 
    url(r'^movement/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.movement_detail, name='movement_detail'),
    url(r'^movement/new/$', views.movement_new, name='movement_new'),
    url(r'^movement/(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/$', views.movement_edit, name='movement_edit'),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.hmac.urls')),
]
```

As it stand right now, the "homepage" for the app is, right now, always the first URL, even with a logged-in user.  How do I show the `views.movement_list` to a logged-in user while the `views.movement_random` to a non-user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to have two views, just set the movements dependant on whether you're authenticated in the single view

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    movements = Movement.objects.filter(author=request.user).order_by('-moved_on')
else:
    movements = Movement.objects.order_by('?')[:10]
```

Comment: I do hope the htmls they are rendering for both views are the same

Comment: @MosesKoledoye - True, but from their use case description, I can't see a reason for them not to be (else just set two variables here for the template name)